# A circle has 2 meanings

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, terminology, circles

We usually write:

> We draw a circle of radius R

But the circle has 2 meanings:

> 1. circumference of a circle

or

> 2. A round plane figure whose boundary consists of points equidistant from the center ([OXFORD dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/circle))

We can write with a one meaning, by not accepted way:

> We draw the circumference of a circle with a radius R.

Do we have an accepted way to write the above sentence?

Comment: Technically, a circle is the boundary of a disc, not the interior, but, in everyday use, the term circle is also used to refer to the interior and the boundary

Comment: I think @Ben that you are right: at the start the word is used ambiguously. But this is resolved (nowadays) by using "circle" for the points at distance $R$ from the centre and "[closed] disc" for the points at distance at most $R$ from the centre.

Comment: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/20931/372

Comment: Bear in mind that mathematicians can't even agree on [whether zero is a natural number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Context is everything for mathematical terminology. To quote from [Lewis Carroll's "Through the Looking Glass"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humpty_Dumpty#Lewis_Carroll's_Through_the_Looking-Glass): *"When **I** use a word," Humpty Dumpty said, in rather a scornful tone, "it means just what I choose it to mean—neither more nor less."*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In standard mathematical terminology, *circle* refers to the curve, while *disk* means the inner (open or closed) region of which the circle is the boundary. A circle can be called a *circumference*, but this term is often used to mean the length. Thus we might write “Let the circle $C$ be the boundary of an open disk $D$ of radius $r$ and circumference $2\pi r$ ”.

In three dimensions, a *sphere* is a (two-dimensional) surface which is the boundary of a (three-dimensional) *ball*.

Comment: More generally, we say that $S^{n-1}$ are those points in $n$-dimensional space of with magnitude $1$, and $B^n$ are those points in $n$-dimensional space with magnitude *at most* $1$. That is, $S^1$ is the circle, and $B^1$ is the disk, and larger $n$ are generalizations.

Comment: What about: ‘the lamp spread a circle of light’

Comment: Making terminological decisions in mathematics can't and doesn't affect the spoken language. Speaking 'circle' for disk is fine in everyday use, however in math we should adopt to the already existing clear distinction.

Comment: @Berci What about: 1) ‘We should have a polygon inscribed in the circle the sides of which coincide with the circumference of the circle.’ 2) ‘Since E lies on the circumference of both circles, it is located at one of the points of intersection.’(OXFORD dictionary)

Comment: @Ben : The Oxford dictionary is good for the mathematical usage of 100 years ago, but is poor on modern usage. Meriam-Webster is more reliable. The first definition (the curve) given by Webster is the one used by mathematicians today, and the second (the region) is the superseded one. Oxford gives the meanings in the reverse order. In everyday parlance, the word *circle* is not used precisely, and its meaning must be determined from context.